# Can I develop flutter desktop app for windows on mac?

Tags: windows, flutter, macos, desktop

Can I develop flutter desktop app for windows on mac? Thanks in advance. I have M1 mac and want to develop app for windows platform.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can write the code on any OS. However in order to compile your code you will have to do it on Windows OS.

See the [documentation](https://docs.flutter.dev/desktop):

> Note: To compile a desktop application, you must build it on the targeted platform: build a Windows application on Windows, a macOS application on macOS, and a Linux application on Linux. If you experience a problem that hasn’t yet been reported, please file an issue and include “desktop:windows win/macos/linux” (whichever platform is appropriate) in the title.

Comment: I will add that for M1 and M2 Mac chipsets, even with windows Paralles, you are NOT able to do it. (I guess due to the arm architecture).
On Macs with an INTEL x86-64 processor I don't know if it is or it isn't possible using Paralles or other virtualizations.